# Flutter how to achieve curve time line view or roadmap view

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to achieve this type of view and I got this concept while surfing the internet.

[image]

So, far what I tried and what I archived I'm sharing here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                const CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  maxRadius: 15,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 200,
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    painter: FaceOutlinePainter(
                      startPoint: const Offset(100, 0),
                      endPoint: const Offset(150, 205),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80.0),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    maxRadius: 15,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FaceOutlinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Offset startPoint;
  final Offset endPoint;

  FaceOutlinePainter({required this.startPoint, required this.endPoint});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 4.0;

    Path path = Path();

    final x0 = startPoint.dx;
    final y0 = startPoint.dy;

    final x3 = endPoint.dx;
    final y3 = endPoint.dy;

    final x1 = x3;
    final y1 = y0;

    final x2 = x0;
    final y2 = y3;

    path.moveTo(x0, y0);
    path.cubicTo(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FaceOutlinePainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Issues:

1. This is not the dynamic view
2. As of now I set curve lines and circles using static coordinates

I'm trying and if I am getting success then I will post the answer.